# Missing virtual destructor in base interface class?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, com, mingw

I have a class deriving (`public`) from IUnknown, whose definition (from file `include/unknwnbase.h` in [MinGW 4.9.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.2/threads-posix/dwarf/)) I paste below:

```
extern "C++" {
  MIDL_INTERFACE("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")
  IUnknown {
  public:
    BEGIN_INTERFACE
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppvObject) = 0;
    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef(void) = 0;
    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release(void) = 0;

    template<class Q>
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(Q **pp) {
      return QueryInterface(__uuidof(Q), (void **)pp);
    }
    END_INTERFACE
  };
}
```

When I compile the derived class, I get the following warning (which in the OpenCV project are treated as error):

> base class 'struct IUnknown' has accessible non-virtual destructor [-Werror=non-virtual-dtor]

I struggle to understand if this is a bug of MinGW (missing virtual destructor) or something else that could be circumvented in the way IUnknown was derived. The OpenCV project is built in several other environments where this warning does not pop up...

Comment: Not sure what those macros do, but try adding an empty virtual destructor?

Comment: i think, it [was fixed lateley](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/3599) you should try a fresh git pull

Comment: @berak I submitted the bug :) , I am up to date with the repository, and the fix unfortunately does not help

Comment: so, please update the resp. issue

Comment: @berak I already did!

Comment: @Antonio: Just a quick comment clarifying that I edited the tags in your question. I wanted to add the `[com]` tag, and since there is a maximum of _five tags_, I was forced to remove an existing tag, and I chose to remove the `[opencv]` tag, since between _COM_ and OpenCV, I thought this question was more related to _COM_. Of course, feel free to adjust the tags and undo my editing if your previous tag choice made better sense to you.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Tried that, thanks, and *seems* to work. I had already thought about that but I had been tricked by OpenCV precompiled headers. See my comment to Mr. C64 answer.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: I believe editing the definition of `IUnknown` (and, in general, editing Win32 SDK header files) is **wrong**. If you have a bug in your C++ toolchain (which is not 100% compatible with COM or other Windows-specific stuff), try fixing that toolchain, instead of _"tempering"_ COM or other Windows Platform SDK headers.

Comment: @Mr.C64 Well, I had no context and no idea what IUnknown is (or whether it was the OP's class).  That's why it was a comment and not an answer.

Comment: The warning is bogus, you never actually call that destructor since IUnknown is an interface.  C++ does not have the notion of interfaces, like languages like Java or C# do, they are emulated with multiple inheritance.  Works, but is not exactly perfect.  Microsoft addressed this by extending their C++ implementation with the `__interface` keyword.  It enforces the interface contract, all members are automatically pure and suppresses generation of the v-table and warnings like this.  Which is what it takes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of COM, lifetime management of objects (and associated cleanup) happens using the `AddRef()` and `Release()` methods of `IUnknown`, via *reference counting*.

Each COM object has a reference count associated with it. When an object's reference count reaches 0 (after e.g. several clients of the object have properly called `Release()` on some COM interface pointer), the object is destroyed. In other words, COM objects are not destroyed in the usual C++ way of calling e.g. `delete` on a base class pointer (and thus requiring proper `virtual` destructors in base classes).
(And, in fact, you can't just call `new` for allocating a COM object. There's more COM machinery that is required.)

In other words, when you're done with a COM interface pointer, you just call `Release()` on it. So there's no need of virtual destructors to be defined in "base classes", like the `IUknown` interface, or other COM interfaces.

So, I suspect that warning is a bug somewhere in your MinGW toolchain.

You're *not* supposed to modify the definition of `IUnknown` in the Windows SDK header file you cited, *neither* should you add a virtual destructor in custom COM interfaces you may define for your purposes.

Comment: Adding `virtual ~IUnknown() {};` *seems* to fix the problem... (Note: as long as I turn off precompiled headers in OpenCV build). What could possibly be the impact of that? It seems a reasonable way to obey to a C++ rule (a class with virtual methods should have a virtual destructor). Note: there's also an unknwn.h file with the same definition. I put the destructor definition before 'END_INTERFACE'

Comment: As stated in my answer, I believe you should _not_ add virtual destructors to your custom COM interfaces, and certainly you should _not_ edit the definition of `IUnknown` adding a virtual destructor. This is not _"ordinary C++"_, this is **COM**, and as I wrote, you can't reason in term of _"pure C++"_ when dealing with COM, since for example you can't just `new` a COM object, but you have to deal with proper COM APIs like `CoCreateInstance()`. Note also that in general you should _not_ modify Windows system header files like the SDK header containing the definition of `IUnknown`.

Comment: I see... But then what's the correct way of getting around this bug?

Comment: Continuing on my first comment, as they say _"When in Rome, do as the Romans do"_, you can paraphrase it as _"When programming COM, do as the COM programmers do"_, i.e. when using COM, follow the COM patterns and idioms. You seem to have a bug in your toolchain, and instead of fixing it, you are introducing some bug in the context of COM.

Comment: Don't you need to use the MIDL compiler for MIDL stuff?